# Shallow rendering unexpected behaviour

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a Component called 'Grid' having a render method like this -

```
render(){
  this.createTable();

  return (
    <div
      style={{display:'flex',justifyContent:'center',flexDirection:'column'}}
    >
      <input
        id='gridFilterText'
        placeholder="filter text here....."
        style={{width:'50%',height:'25px',borderRadius:'4px'}}
        onChange={this.onType} 
        value={this.state.value}
      ></input>
      <table style={{flex:'0.5',borderRadius:'4px',boxShadow:'-1px 3px 4px 0px black'}}>
        <thead style={{textDecoration:'underline'}}>
          <tr>
            {this.headerArr}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.tableBody}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

createTable() {
  this.headerArr = this.props.headerList.map((item,index)=>(
    <th key={index}>
      {item}
    </th>
  ));

  this.tableBody = this.filteredProdList.map((item,index)=>(
    <tr key={index} onMouseOver={this.onFocus} onMouseOut={this.onFocusRemove}>
      {Object.keys(item).map((key,index)=>(
        <td key={index}>{item[key]}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  ))
}
```

I was trying to test this with this test (Jest and Enzyme) script -

```
test('Grid filters properly',()=>{
  const gridWrapper=mount(<Grid headerList={['Id','Name','Stock']} prodList={items}/>);
  const textBoxWrapper=gridWrapper.find('#gridFilterText');
  textBoxWrapper.simulate('change',{target:{value:'p'}});  
  gridWrapper.update();
  console.log(textBoxWrapper.debug());

  expect(
    gridWrapper
    .find('table')
    .children()
    .find('tbody')
    .children()
  ).toHaveLength(2);
})
```

What I am trying to acheive here is -

1. Render the Grid component
2. The grid component has a  control in it (its not a child component)
3. Simulate an OnChange on the  control by setting value (value ='p')
4. This should cause the grid to show filtered output (2 rows)

Why it works only if I use mount and it does not work if I use shallow.
As per my understanding shallow works on the component and does go down to the child components. 
In this case,  is part of the  component and not its child component, right?

Please let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: What is `tableBody` in your render function? If it's a different component, that would explain the issue (given `shallow` would not look at how that renders). If that's the case, you probably need to either use `mount` to make a more integration level test, or write a narrower test using `shallow` that only tests what the component itself manages. You'll need to provide a bit more detail on exactly how your component is filtering the output to be able to provide a solid example of the latter though.

Comment: I have updated more details. Basically, the the render method is calling another method which is creating the table body. Not calling any separate Component from there.